# Rails - Up/Down Button Save to database

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement drag and drop to my application, which is working on a desktop browser using jquery-ui.

I can not get it working on a touch device for love nor money and would like to implement up/down buttons. I have got this working however cannot figure out how to save to the database.

View

```
<ul class="products-list product-list-in-box" id="activity" data-url="<%= pages_sort_path %>" >
        <% @todays_customers.each do |today| %>
                <li class="" id="activity_<%= today.activity_id %>">
                    <div> <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i> 
                   <span class="pull-right">
                     [ <a href="#" class="up_sub" id="1_3">Up</a> ] 
                     [ <a href="#" class="down_sub" id="1_3">Down</a> ]
                   <% if today.activity_type == 'Journey Day' %>
                   <span class="label bg-red"><%= link_to "x", customer_activity_path(today.customer_id, today.activity_id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></span>
                   <% end %>
                    </span>

                  </div>
            </li>        
            <% end %>

        </ul>
```

JS

```
    <script>
    $( function() {
    $( "#activity" ).sortable({
     axis: "y",
     update: function(e, ui) {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data("url"),
            type: "PATCH",
            data: $(this).sortable('serialize')
        })
     }
});
    $( "#activity" ).disableSelection();
  } );


 $('.up_sub').click(function(){
    var li = $(this).closest('li');
    var prev = li.prev();
    if(prev.length){
        li.detach().insertBefore(prev);
    }
    ;
    console.log($(this))
});
$('.down_sub').click(function(){
    var li = $(this).closest('li');
    var next = li.next();
    if(next.length){
        li.detach().insertAfter(next);
    }
   ;
      console.log($(this))
});
  </script>
```

Controller

```
 def sort

  params[:activity].each_with_index do |id, index|
    Activity.where(id: id).update_all(position: index + 1)
  end

  head :ok

  end
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to replicate the way that the drag and drop sends the params of each li entry id in sequence after the drop. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend you to use [acts_at_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem. So all things you need to do is using `update` action and passing the new `position` value of the record you want to drag/drop. `acts_at_list` will handle the rest then.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at acts as list however because the collection @todays_customers is made up from joins and not one model then i didn't think it would work.

Comment: Using acts_as_list for `activity ` model should work, I guess.

Comment: Even if `activity` is used elsewhere and not show in a "acts as list" type view?